# Is there anyway to check whether an attribute in a Domain Class is a Primary Key?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, primary-key

I need to know whether a certain attribute of a domain class is a primary key. Is there any way to do this?

For example, I have a domain class Person.groovy(uses hibernate) which I loaded dynamically this class belongs to a separate plugin.

```
class Person{    
static mapping = {
    table 'PERSON'
    // version is set to false, because this isn't available by default for legacy databases
    version false
    id column:'PERSON_ID'
}
Long personId
String name
String address
static constraints = {}
}
```

I have another class that loads the domain class dynamically and it needs to check whether the attribute is a Primary Key or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the identifier property of a domain object by:

```
// Get a single Person and interrogate the domainClass
def idProp = Person.find {}.domainClass.identifier
```

You should then be able to call one of the [methods on the GrailsDomainClassProperty interface](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClassProperty.html), ie:

```
println idProp.name
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your response. However, when I try to get the identifier, I always get the result "id" even if my identifier has a different name.